# Google Analytics doesn't work for 'today'

Tags: analytics

I have been using Google Analytics for some time now but it doesn't work for today (it tells me how many views I had yesterday and this month et cetera but it won't show me what the statistics for today are). I have been experimenting with my HTML code but I don't know if I made a mistake doing that. I am using the 'official' tracking code my Google Analytics account gives me.
I hope somebody'll be able to help me.

My website is www.lemontierres.com

Friendly regards

Answer (score 0):

Statistics and reports for the current day are delayed in Analytics.  It is not real time.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I used to be able to do this: whenever I chose 'today' it told me how many views I had for the day. How is it possible I can't do this anymore?